# Concatenate in R after every 10 rows

Tags: r, dataframe, concatenation, paste

I have a data frame with 113 rows, I want to concatenate every 10 rows.

I am trying something like this:

```
test<-runif(113)
test2<-paste(test, collapse", ")
```

I don't know who I can specify for every 10 rows.

Comment: Please specify a sample input and a sample output so it's clearer what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

First, you have a vector, not a data frame.

Second, the paste syntax is malformed (it probably is tossing an error for you).

You can use the following to split the vector every 10 elements, perform the concatenation and get the results back as a character vector.

```
test2 <- unlist(lapply(split(test, ceiling(seq_along(test)/10)), paste, collapse=", "))
```

The `seq_along` creates the "groups" and the `split`, divides the vector along those groups. The `lapply` then performs the `paste` on those groups and the `unlist` converts the result back to a character vector.

Comment: It's also unclear what the OP means by "concatenate," as it makes no sense to combine numeric values into some character string.

Comment: Unless the OP is trying to make something to output with `writeLines` (which was my first assumption). I agree, it's a curious situation requiring building such a structure.

Answer (score 2):

If it is a `data.frame`

```
set.seed(42)
d1 <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(1:20, 4*113,replace=TRUE), ncol=4))
indx <- (seq_len(nrow(d1))-1)%/%10 +1
lapply(split(d1, indx), function(x) paste(unlist(x), collapse=", "))
```

Or

```
 unname(c(by(d1, list(indx), FUN=function(x) paste(unlist(x), collapse=", "))))
```